# HighCharts dateformat does not have microseconds (%f)

Tags: javascript, highcharts, strftime

I want microsecond accuracy in my HighChart plot.
Something like this

```
xDateFormat: '%e/%b/%Y - %H:%M:%S:%f'
```

However I get the "%f" printed as is instead..
Since this library uses PHP's strftime date format, I went over to http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php and found that this indeed doesn't have any option for microsecond.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is :%f means ? I know about %L...

Comment: bro thats the answer. %L works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use `%L` instead of `%f`.

```
millisecond: '%L'
second: '%S'
minute: '%M'
hour: '%H'
```